# HTML 5 Video uses a lot of CPU (on a MacBook)

Tags: html, video, fullscreen, cpu-usage

I've run into a problem with a HTML5 video.
I use an HTML5 video (MP4 and WebM) to run almost full screen on my website.
The video is working fine. It auto-plays the video, and repeats playing.
The only thing is: it uses a lot of CPU.
I've tested it on 2 MacBooks, and both use about 20-40% of my CPU. 
My fan is running as fast as it can (6000 rpm). 
I really don't know what is causing that use CPU usage. 
The video files are about 32mb big.

The website is: http://atention.sw-dev.nl/ 
(Written in Dutch).

I really appreciate your help.